# How to manually split data by label

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data A and i want to divide it into training data and test data based on what we input, for example 50% or 70% but according to each class. Suppose I input 50% it will be like this:
[image]

I tried using `train_test_split` but that method uses all the data, then divides it as much as we want instead of dividing it by label like i'm trying to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it may helpful to you

```
import pandas as pd

# create random data
d = {'label': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value': [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)  # creating dataframe

split_factor = 0.5
#  initializing data frames
train_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label', 'value'])
test_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label', 'value'])

# get all unique labels
unique_labels = df['label'].unique()

# store length of every unique label
unique_lengths = {}
for uni in unique_labels:
    unique_lengths[uni] = int(len(df[df.label == uni]) * split_factor) # updated on the suggestion on codingPhobia


for uni in unique_labels:
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if(row['label'] == uni):
            if(unique_lengths[uni]):  # if unique klength is not equal to 0
                train_data = train_data.append({'label': row['label'], 'value': row['value']}, ignore_index=True)
                unique_lengths[uni] = unique_lengths[uni] - 1  # minus unique lengths value
            else:

                test_data = test_data.append({'label': row['label'], 'value': row['value']}, ignore_index=True)

print('test data')
print(train_data)
print('train_data')
print(test_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but doesn't StratifiedShuffleSplit require to randomize the order of the data?
What I want is that the data stays in the same order as in data A, then when divided, the data at the end of the label becomes as much test data as we input

Comment: Answer is updated

Comment: Thank you for your help, with the help of comments I really helped in understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

Mudasir Habib answer is perfect but you are missing one thing you need to wrap unique_lengths in int like

```
unique_lengths[uni] = int(len(df[df.label == uni]) * split_factor)
```

So the whole code will be

```
import pandas as pd

# create random data
d = {'label': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value': [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)  # creating dataframe

split_factor = 0.8
#  initializing data frames
train_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label', 'value'])
test_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label', 'value'])

# get all unique labels
unique_labels = df['label'].unique()

# store length of every unique label
unique_lengths = {}
for uni in unique_labels:
    unique_lengths[uni] = int(len(df[df.label == uni]) * split_factor)


for uni in unique_labels:
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if(row['label'] == uni):
            if(unique_lengths[uni]):  # if unique klength is not equal to 0
                train_data = train_data.append({'label': row['label'], 'value': row['value']}, ignore_index=True)
                unique_lengths[uni] = unique_lengths[uni] - 1  # minus unique lengths value
            else:

                test_data = test_data.append({'label': row['label'], 'value': row['value']}, ignore_index=True)

print('test data')
print(train_data)
print('train_data')
print(test_data)
```